# Could not synchronize database state with session org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not update:

Tags: spring, hibernate

Hi I am getting the error in the logs, please let me know hwat is wrong with session.

```
[9/17/15 12:49:12:127 BST] 00000015 SystemOut O 2015-09-17 12:49:12 WARN JDBCExceptionReporter:100 - SQL Error: -911, SQLState: 40001
[9/17/15 12:49:12:128 BST] 00000015 SystemOut O 2015-09-17 12:49:12 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:101 - DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-911, SQLSTATE=40001, SQLERRMC=2, DRIVER=3.58.81
[9/17/15 12:49:12:136 BST] 00000015 SystemOut O 2015-09-17 12:49:12 ERROR AbstractFlushingEventListener:324 - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not update: [*********]
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:105)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2443)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2325)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2625)
at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:115)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:168)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1028)
at com.persistance.ApplicationDAOImpl.getUniqueId(ApplicationDAOImpl.java:573)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy52.getCapeUniqueId(Unknown Source)
at com.util.CapeSequenceGenerator.getCapeUniqueId(SequenceGenerator.java:32)
at com..serviceimpl.CreditApplicationServiceImpl.processAppMessage(ApplicationServiceImpl.java:148)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
```

Caused by:

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.to: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-911, SQLSTATE=40001, SQLERRMC=2, DRIVER=3.58.81
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:663)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:60)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.ed.a(ed.java:127)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.tm.c(tm.java:2523)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.fb.s(fb.java:940)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.fb.k(fb.java:390)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.fb.a(fb.java:61)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.t.a(t.java:50)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.vb.b(vb.java:218)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.um.jc(um.java:2860)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.um.b(um.java:3795)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.um.ac(um.java:709)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.um.executeUpdate(um.java:692)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.pmiExecuteUpdate(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:1185)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:802)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.NonBatchingBatcher.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatcher.java:46)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2421)
... 45 more
```

Below is my code which is causing the above error

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Sequence.class);

List capeSequence = criteria.list();   
for (Iterator iterator = capeSequence.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
  Sequence uniqueSequence = (Sequence)iterator.next();
  existingId = uniqueSequence.getSequence();
  minVal = uniqueSequence.getMinVal();
  maxVal = uniqueSequence.getMaxVal();
}
if (existingId == maxVal) {            
  existingId = minVal;         
} else {
  existingId = existingId+1;
}

Sequence eequenceObj = (CSequence) session.get(Sequence.class, SEQUENCE_NAME, LockMode.UPGRADE);
SequenceObj.setSequence(existingId);
session.update(capeSequenceObj);
session.flush();
```

Comment: Your code sample do not show the definition of all the variables used. For example, what are the types of : existingId, minVal, maxVal, SequenceObj, SEQUENCE_NAME (and it's content ?) ? What is CSequence compared to Sequence ?

Comment: In service class calling DAO method through synchronized method. In my DAO IMPL class the below method.